# Is it possible to use synergy with a single monitor and 3 desktops?

Tags: windows-xp, kvm-switch

Is it possible to use synergy with a single monitor and 3 desktops?
All running XP. I'm trying to avoid buying a KVM switch...

Right. Still trying to use a single keyboard and mouse, but w/3 desktops and a single monitor. Just need a simple switching solution. Currently, I'm using VNC to remote in to the other PC's, but it seems silly since they're all lined up right next to each other. I just have no need for multiple monitors.

Comment: Synergy is for sharing keyboard and mouse between computers, not for sharing monitors.

Comment: Right. Still trying to use a single keyboard and mouse, but w/3 desktops and a single monitor. Just need a simple switching solution. Currently, I'm using VNC to remote in to the other PC's, but it seems silly since they're all lined up right next to each other. I just have no need for multiple monitors.

Comment: @user74230: you can get a 4 port KVM switch for about $15-20 these days, is it really worth the trouble?

Comment: You do realize that VNC *is* "Synergy with a single monitor and 3 desktops"? Aside from a hardware solution, this is what you want.

Comment: Huh, guess not so much. I didn't really check prices. Thx for the tip. Still, if it is possible, it'd be worth knowing.

Comment: The original author of Synergy talked about eventually making it so that it was a full software KVM solution, but that never seemed to get anywhere. Probably hard to do properly, but damn it would be cool.

Answer (score 4):

Well to be Honest it depends.  Do you have a newer monitor with multiple connections? Your monitor can have one desktop on VGA and 1 on DVI (And 1 on HDMI if you have it).  Set the Connections up using Synergy before ditching the other monitors.  Then Switch between connections by scrolling to the next screen with the mouse and then hitting the switch input option on the monitor.

Answer (score 3):

Synergy is a way of sharing the keyboard and mouse amongst multiple computers each with their own monitor.  It is like having one big desktop shared out across multiple monitors.

What you cannot do is share the screen.

For that you either need a KVM switch or to continue using VNC.